Вместо текстового значения в поле бд заносятся цифры (индексы tuple) django
У меня есть tuple городов:
City_CHOICES = (
    ("1", "Волгоград"),
    ("2", "Волжский"),
    ("3", "Быково"),
    ("4", "Городище"),
    ...
    ("18", "Другое"),
 )

В модели ArtPerson есть поле city:
class ArtPerson(models.Model):
    ...
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="Волгоград", verbose_name="Город художника", choices=City_CHOICES,)
...

При добавлении нового человека в БД через админ панель в бд почему-то записывается число (например, 1, если введён Волгоград, 2, если введён Волжский).
Приходится в DB Browser вручную исправлять числа на слова.
Как решить данную проблему? Благодарна любым дельным советам.

Логично, вы же сами указали цифры в качестве значений в City_CHOICES. Хотите не цифры — значит напишите вместо цифр то, что вы хотите

Так ?  City_CHOICES = (
("Волгоград", "Волгоград"),
("Волжский", "Волжский"),
("Быково", "Быково"),....    ) А возможно вообще использовать список ["Волгоград", "Волжский" ...], а то масло масленое получается

Всё работает, спасибо за помощь!!!
